# How to ignore specific bower javascript library in gulp (regex issue maybe)?

Tags: gulp, bower

I am using the "main-bower-files" gulp plugin. There is a bower library that is huge... I want to ignore it in my list called "fatjslib.js". My current regex filter is as follows:

```
   var listOfBower = mainBowerFiles({filter: (/.*\.js$/i)});
```

This picks up "fatjslib.js" and when I print out the above variable, I see:

```
"\\User\\kmichaels\\storage\\app\\bower_components\\fatjslib\FatJsLib\FatJsLib.js"
```

How can I specify the filter or change regex, or do something such that the "listOfBower" can ignore the "FatJsLib.js" file? I don't want to specify the whole path if possible, if there is a way to wildcard ignore anything regardless of pathstructure with "FatJsLib", that may be best, but I am open to suggestions. Is the solution flexible to add "AnotherBigLib.js" (should there be a second library under some path structure) to the regex or ignore list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way for the "main-bower-files" plugin to stop reading specific bower library is to pass the [overrides](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files#overrides) option in the param or to set the [overrides](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files#overrides-options) property in `bower.json`

**METHOD 1: To pass the overrides param:**

Pass the `overrides` option to the `mainBowerFiles()`and set the `ignore` property to `true` for the library you wish to ignore.

```
var listOfBower = mainBowerFiles({"overrides":{"fatjslib":{"ignore":true}}});
```

**METHOD 2: Specify overrides property in bower.json**

You can also specify [overrides](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files#overrides-options) property in `bower.json` and then there will be no need to pass overrides option as a param. When `main-bower-files` plugin will read the bower.json file, it will [ignore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files#ignore) the libraries that are set in overrides property with ignore flag to true.

in bower.json add an `overrides` property:

```
"overrides": {
    "fatjslib": {
        "ignore": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in case `fatjslib` contains multiple js files, and you just want to ignore one while as include another, then you can override main section of the package.

Every package comes with its own bower.json which has a main section. This section contains the file to be injected.

What you can do is, in overrides - override the main section just to keep the files you want to be injected

```
"overrides": {
    "fatjslib": {
      "main": ["./dist/another-file.js"]
    }
  }
```

and then provide these overrides to `mainBowerFiles`

Answer (score 0):

How about modifying the regex as follows:

```
/^(?!.*FatJsLib\.js$).*\.js$/i
```

And to add more libraries:

```
/^(?!.*(?:FatJsLib|AnotherBigLib)\.js$).*\.js$/i
```

Also, if you want to filter anything with *FatJsLib* in its path try with:

```
/^(?!.*\\(?:FatJsLib|AnotherBigLib)\\.*$).*\.js$/i
```

**Source:** I wrote the regex, you can try it [here](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=93841). Also the main-bower-files documentation states that [filter can use any regex](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files#filter).